# How can I do a zoom with the browser via the keyboard and without a scrollwheel?

Tags: windows-8, browser

I have a notebook without a scoll wheel. What is the keyboard command for zooming in the browser? I wanto be able to zoom to 100% on a page that is blown up to 150%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + scroll wheel would work, but in your case as explained on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5815125/how-to-zoom-in-and-out-on-a-web-page):

> In order to zoom in, you just press control (Windows) or command (Mac)
>   and the <kbd>+</kbd> key. (Technically you're pressing the
>   <kbd>=</kbd> key because you'd need to press <kbd>shift</kbd> to make
>   a plus, but thinking of it as the <kbd>+</kbd> key makes more sense
>   since it's zooming you in.) To zoom out, press control/command
>   <kbd>-</kbd>, and press <kbd>control</kbd>/<kbd>command</kbd>
>   <kbd>0</kbd> to set things back to normal.

Comment: You should add the relevant info here so link rot doesn't render your answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

Not a shortcut via keyboard but still may solve your issue:

Some mousepad drivers allow you to zoom via gesture (e.g. "un-pinching"). Go to Settings > Hardware and Sound > Mouse.

If you have a Synaptics touchpad, there will be a "Device Settings" tab. The entry which mentions the touchpad should be highlighted. Then, click on "Settings"

[image]
<sub>[Source](https://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD3101Z30000R01.htm)</sub>

Another window should pop up. The settings of the so-called "pinch zoom" should be somewhere.

[image]
<sub>[Source](https://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD3101Z30000R01.htm)</sub>

If you don't have such a touchpad, you have to look for similar settings in the mouse properties window or somewhere else in the hardware settings.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Question is about using **keyboard** to scroll.

Comment: @DavidPostill This question is somewhat a [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/270378). I suggest a solution to the problem of *not having a scroll wheel*. The solution of *that* problem does not necessarily have to have a keyboard involved.

Comment: The question clearly asked "What is the **keyboard** command for zooming in the browser?"

Comment: @DavidPostill I am well aware of this but I still see this question as a question about a XY problem. I think that people who never heard of touchpad gestures would think only about a keyboard shortcut. My answer still solves the original problem. It's not like I'm discussing how zooming is bad for UX.

Comment: Well we have to agree to differ in this case ;) Note that one of the other answers also proposes a solution not using the keyboard and similar comments to mine have been made on that answer by others.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know if this applies to this question: http://meta.superuser.com/q/8281/181179

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl and + zooms out

Ctrl and - zooms in

Ctrl and 0 restores view to 100%

I use this daily and it works not just for browsers alone but also windows desktop, Adobe photoshop, and many other apps.

Comment: Incorrect. Ctrl+ zooms in, Ctrl- zooms out.